# How to tell playwright to fall back to debian dependencies instead of ubuntu dependencies? (Or make it believe it is on debian as alternative)

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, playwright

### Background

I want to install [linkwarden](https://docs.linkwarden.app/self-hosting/installation#manual-installation) on a raspberry pi 4 running [dietpi 9](https://dietpi.com/). Linkwarden uses playwright. I want to install it bare metal so that I do not have to install docker which is a on-top-layer of complexity I would have to secure. (I am not very fluent with docker either). Dietpi 9 is based on debian bookworm which is officially supported by playwright. It is more lightweight than debian and thoroughly tested on rpi. I run debian on most of my machines but I think on a rpi dietpi is the better choice at the moment.

### Problem

When installing playwright by `npx playwright install-deps` it fails with a couple of package dependencies not met. It does try to solve that by falling back to ubuntu dependencies which does not work out. It would most probably work out when it would use debian dependencies instead of ubuntu since dietpi itself uses debian packages.

### Questions

Is there a way to make playwright use debian dependencies?

If not, is there a way to make playwright believe it is run on debian bookworm instead of dietpi 9?

Thank you.